# how to enable indexing for search in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: search

How to enable indexing for search in SharePoint 2010 sites.
We want enable this for a couple of sites  on our portal.

Many thanks,

Comment: Who downvoted this without adding comments or suggestions? If you're thinking 'just google it' then say so. In related news: http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-enterprise-search-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 5):

Plenty of sources on the net for details about this (like the one I posted in the comments), but basically:

- Set up a Search Service Application
- Add the Content Sources (the SharePoint sites you want to crawl)
- Start a full crawl.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the search service started and configured first. Have you done this yet?

Comment: Thanks guys. Basically you just setup search  and then add the content sources, then you are done?!